# How to check if string has at least one letter, number and special character in php

Tags: php, regex, string, special-characters

I am currently writing a small script that checks the contents of each string.

I was wondering what the REGEX would be to make sure that a string has a letter (upper or lower), a digit, and a special character?

Here is what I know so far (whcih isn't much):

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i', $string)):
```

Help would be great!

Thank You!

Comment: Please define what you mean by "special character"

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The easiest (and probably best) way is to do three separate checks with `preg_match`:

```
$containsLetter  = preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/',    $string);
$containsDigit   = preg_match('/\d/',          $string);
$containsSpecial = preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $string);

// $containsAll = $containsLetter && $containsDigit && $containsSpecial
```

Comment: @rybo111: No, they can’t. `A-z` contains more characters than `a-zA-Z`.

Comment: @rybo111: Please stop editing my answer to be less clear. Nobody “requested if()”, and it’s not like you can’t use variables in one.

Comment: What if I want to do something if it doesn't contain letter and numbers, instead of contain it?

Comment: @Freedo: `!$containsLetter` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 14):

You can use positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to create a single regex:

```
$strongPassword = preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$%^&]).*$/');
//                                              special characters  ^^^^
```

Answer (score 14):

I have found great answer here with explanation to make sure that a given string contains at least one character from each of the following categories.

Lowercase character,
Uppercase character,
Digit,
Symbol

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$
```

A short explanation:

`^`                  // the start of the string

`(?=.*[a-z])`        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one lower case letter exists

`(?=.*[A-Z])`        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one upper case letter exists

`(?=.*\d)`           // use positive look ahead to see if at least one digit exists

`(?=.*[_\W])`        // use positive look ahead to see if at least one underscore or non-word character exists

`.+`                 // gobble up the entire string

`$`                  // the end of the string

Hope that help you.

Answer (score 5):

False (chosen answer above - Thanks!) had the a pretty easy way to wrap your head around it (if you aren't too familiar with regex) and come up with what works for you.

I just put this in to elaborate a bit:

(you can paste it at http://phptester.net/index.php?lang=en to work with it)

```
<?php

$pass="abc1A";

$ucl = preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $pass); // Uppercase Letter
$lcl = preg_match('/[a-z]/', $pass); // Lowercase Letter
$dig = preg_match('/\d/', $pass); // Numeral
$nos = preg_match('/\W/', $pass); // Non-alpha/num characters (allows underscore)

if($ucl) {
    echo "Contains upper case!<br>";
}

if($lcl) {
    echo "Contains lower case!<br>";
}

if($dig) {
    echo "Contains a numeral!<br>";
}

// I negated this if you want to dis-allow non-alphas/num:
if(!$nos) {
    echo "Contains no Symbols!<br>"; 
}

if ($ucl && $lcl && $dig && !$nos) { // Negated on $nos here as well
    echo "<br>All Four Pass!!!";
} else {
    echo "<br>Failure...";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be best to use 3 distinct regexs to do this, since you would need to match 6 different possibilities, depending on where your special characters are in your string. But if you want to do it in one regex, and your special characters are, say, [+?@], it is possible:

```
$string = "abc@123";
$regex = "/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$%^&]).*$/"
if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
   // special characters
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A letter is `\pL`, a number is `\pN` and a special char is `[what you want]`, here I assume it is not a letter and not a number, so the regex looks like:

```
/^(?=.*?\pL)(?=.*?\pN)(?=.*[^\pL\pN])/
```

Comment: It's nice you include non-english characters. often overlooked.